# Viewing Trello cards I am subscribed to

Tags: trello, trello-cards

Is there a way to view all of the cards to which I am subscribed in Trello? I would like to be able to see a listing of all the cards that I am subscribed to (similar to viewing all cards which you are a member of), but I don't see anywhere in the menus that you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on your user portrait in the top right of the web application, you will see an option 'Cards'. Clicking this will display a list of all the cards you are subscribed to.

You then have the option to sort this list either 'By Board' or 'By Due Date'

Comment: I suppose it's a wrong answer. If I unsubscribe from a card it remains on my cards list. So I'm still curious where to find the list of all cards I'm subscribed to.

Comment: That shows cards you're a Member of, not what you're Subscribed to.